# SQL select query to output results from 3 tables based on 1 criteria

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

**Doctor**:

```
staff_no - doctor_name
50       -  smith
100      -  jones
150      -  blogs
```

**Prescription**:

```
pre_no - staff_no - patient_id - start_date
100    -  50      -   10        -  01/01/2008
101    -  100     -   11        -  02/02/2009
102    -  150     -   12        -  03/03/2008
```

**Treatment**:

```
staff_no - patient_id - start_date
50       -    10      -     01/01/2008
100      -    11      -     01/02/2009
150      -    12      -     02/03/2008
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a table which looks like the following with the following conditions, show how many people have had treatments and prescriptions issued during the year 2009 using the AS keyword to generate the last 2 columns

```
staff_no - doctor_name - number_of_patients_treated - number of prescriptions_issued
100      -  Jones      -        1                    -            1
```

Only Jones has issued both treatments and meds within the year 2009 and he has done this on 1 occurrence.

so far I have come up with the following but cannot think how to incorporate both the date for treatment and prescription, also I get syntax errors with the count condition in there. any help would be mucho mucho appreciated, thanks.

```
select 
   d.staff_no, doctor_name, 
   Count(t.patient_id) as number_of_different_patients_treated
from 
   doctor d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   treatment t on d.staff_no = t.staff_no
WHERE 
   t.start_date LIKE '%2009%'
```

Comment: what data type is `start_date`?

Comment: 1. You need to group the data to do the count. That means use `Group By` clause. 2. For Dates use date function.

Comment: start_date is just a string I think, comparing it using "like" works fine

Comment: think I saw an example on here which looked like it would do the job but its gone now :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select 
   d.staff_no, 
   d.doctor_name, 
   Count(distinct t.patient_id) as [number_of_different_patients_treated],
   Count(p.patient_id) as [number of prescriptions_issued]
from doctor d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   treatment t 
   on d.staff_no = t.staff_no
and year(t.start_date) = 2009 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   Prescription p 
   on d.staff_no = p.staff_no
and year(p.start_date) = 2009
where p.staff_no is not null or t.staff_no is not null 
group by d.staff_no, d.doctor_name
order by d.doctor_name
```

You could use LIKE '%2009' if it really is a string (it shouldn't be.)  Or if it is a date, instead of using year() you could use

```
t.start_date between '1/1/2009' and '12/31/2009 23:59'
```

Not sure if you want the unique patients (the distinct) or not? If not, just remove the "distinct".

Comment: hi brookes that's great, the only thing missing which I didn't specify was that results that don't equal at least 1 in both columns shouldn't be included, how can I specify that?

Comment: and it is a date you were correct the year function works great.

Comment: @user3783811, just change the LEFT OUTER JOIN to an INNER JOIN and you should get that result.

Comment: @AHiggins, I think you wouldn't count the doctors that didn't have a prescription if you did that.  Sorry, just reread the new requirement. Yes, your way is better if they need to be in both.

Comment: @user3783811 I added a WHERE clause to eliminate the doctors that didn't have either.